# MS TEAMS - mail notification to all team members for specific channel post

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have an Announcement channel(public) in MS Teams. I want an email to be sent to all team/channel members whenever there is a post on that channel. I know its opposite to how it is intended to be but emails are still in demand.

Comment: Could you please try to subscribe to [channel notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-beta) in graph API and send mail using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).if that helps?

Comment: Thanks @Nikitha-MSFT, I got another idea, Creating teams create an Office 365 group with an email ID, Do you know who all will receive an email if I send mail to that email ID, all team members, is it?

Comment: when you send mails using team mail address, the mail will be posted to specific team or channel where everyone can view the mail.

Comment: yeah not very useful in my case, I built MS Flow / Power Automate to perform the job. Thanks for your help :)